# Hiding div then posting form

Tags: php, jquery

I'm still working on my multi-stage form (http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/93/) and have incorporated the following solution to assist in ajax submit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#postData").click(function() {
        $("#last-step").hide(600);

            $("#task5_booking").submit(function() {
                $.post('resources/process2.php', function(data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                });
            });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

It fades out the last step well but when it comes to loading up the content ot process2.php which is simply an array of all the form fields:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Nothing seems to happen at all. The div remains blank. Would really appreciate any help guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you call a resource via ajax you should also pass the serialized form along the call. So assuming `$("#task5_booking")` is your form element

```
$("#task5_booking").submit(function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $.post('resources/process2.php', { data: $("#task5_booking").serialize() }, function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
      });
});
```

When you submit the form

1. stop the default event (submit) otherwise the form submission stops immediately the subsequent code and the ajax call never starts - this is done using `preventDefault()` method;
2. make a post call, passing the form serialized with `serialize()` method (see http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Please also note that as pointed out by Jack your form in the fiddle has  `camperapplicationForm` id and not `task5_booking`

Comment: Serialize will retun string like "param1=val1&param2=val2", but second $.post parameter must be an object whith "name":value pairs like this: {"param1":111, "param2:222"}. It's look like error for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove your `submit` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#postData").click(function() {
        $("#last-step").hide(600);


        $.post('resources/process2.php', function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, and F. Calderan is right, you should send your form data along the Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#postData").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#last-step").hide(600);

            $("#task5_booking").submit(function() {
                $.post('resources/process2.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                });
            });
    });
});
```